# Fragment Manager

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment, fragment-manager

Есть приложение в нем `CardView` выводится поверх `RecyclerView`. На `CardView` есть элемент который по нажатию выбивает меню. Нужно что-бы по нажатию на пункт меню появлялся `AlertDialog`, попытался сделать так:

```
DialogFragment editDialog = new AlertDialogEdit();
editDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), " ");
```

проблема в том что в классе адаптера где все это у меня прописывается, не хочет создаваться метод `getFragmentManager()`студия выделяет его красным, хотя такой же метод в любом другом классе вызывается нормально. Объясните пожалуйста, что может быть не так.

Код Адаптера:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<RecyclerItem> listItems;
private Activity activity;
DialogFragment editDialog = new AlertDialogEdit();

public RecyclerAdapter( Activity activity, List<RecyclerItem> listItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listItems = listItems;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();;
    holder.txtTitle.setText(listItems.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(listItems.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.txtOptionDigit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, holder.txtOptionDigit);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.option_menu);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.mnu_item_edit:
                            editDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Edited", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case R.id.mnu_item_delete:
                            listItems.remove(position);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView txtTitle;
    public TextView txtDescription;
    public TextView txtOptionDigit;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        txtDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        txtOptionDigit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtOptionDigit);
    }
}}
```

Код класса отвечающего за AlertDialog:

```
  public class AlertDialogEdit extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_dialog, null);
    v.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
    v.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            Log.d("Log", "Ok");
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Log.d("Log", "Cancel");
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Объясните пожалуйста, что может быть не так.

Когда Вы вызываете какой-то метод без указания класса, то этот метод должен быть определен либо непосредственно в классе, из которого вызывается метод, либо в классе от которого наследуется текущий класс, либо в интерфейсе, который реализует данный класс, должна быть реализация этого метода по-умолчанию (*default methods*).

Так как метод `getFragmentManager()` не определен ни в классе `RecyclerAdapter`, ни в классе `RecyclerView.Adapter`, то Вы получаете ошибку на этапе компиляции, которая гласит о том, что данный метод не определен.

Метод `getFragmentManager()` доступен для класса `Activity` и его субклассов, и для класса `Fragment` и его субклассов.

Один из методов решения данной проблемы:

1. Определить интерфейс с методом (*callback*), который будет вызываться из адаптера при клике на определенный элемент;
2. Реализовать определенный в первом пункте интерфейс в активити (оттуда будет доступен метод `getFragmentManager()`);

Answer (score 1):

`getFragmentManager()` - это метод класса активити. Поэтому он и не доступен в классе адаптера - он не расширяет активити. Вам надо бы, по хорошему, создать интерфейс-слушатель кликов, реализовать его в активити/фрагменте, передать его в адаптер и в нужный момент дёргать метод - он будет вызван в активити и проблемы этой не возникнет и красивее будет.

В качестве временного костыля вы можете просто взять контекст любой вьюхи, скастовать его к активити и так вызвать метод:

```
((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager()
```